# How to access the model of another RequestMapping in the same Controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How do I make the objects associated to a RequestMapping in a controller be accessible by another RequestMapping in the same controller that returns to the same view page? Thank you.

Here is my sample code which is placed in only one controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="firstMapping",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView firstMapping (HttpServletRequest request) {

    //myObject is processed here

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("samplepage");
    mav.addObject("myObject",myObject); //How do I pass this object to the mapping below?
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="secondMapping",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView secondMapping (HttpServletRequest request) {

    //I want to do something else here but I need the object from
    //the mapping above. For example myObject2 is processed here

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("samplepage");

    mav.addObject("myObject",myObject);
    mav.addObject("myObject2",myObject2);
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you combine both methods, If you need both data in one request?

Comment: mrkernelpanic, I can't because the two methods process different things but if I don't pass the object processed in the first controller to the second controller, the object in the first method will be gone but I need the object in the second method.

Answer (score 0):

In the first method, instead of setting a view you should forward the request to the second method after setting the attribute.Set view in second method.By using this request is forwarded to the second method after processing.

```
@RequestMapping(value="firstMapping",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView firstMapping (HttpServletRequest request) {
    Object myObject=new Object();
   request.setAttribute("myObject",myObject);
    return "forward:/secondMapping";
}
```

you can also use ModelandView to carry object from method 1 to 2.

Comment: Thanveer, could you give a sample code on how will the method 2 receive the object? Thank you